# A function to change property e.g. forecolor and backcolor of any control

Tags: c#, function, controls

Is it possible to have a function to get a control name (label, texbox, button, etc) and based on the input argument, change e.g. forecolor, backcolor, enable properties of that control?

Here is what I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1859939/3179989 but it should know the type of control.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
 public void SetControl(string ControlName, string Operation)
    {
        Control Control = this.Controls.Find(ControlName, true)[0];
        if (Operation=="Green")
        {
            Control.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            Control.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
        }
    }
```

do you have any better solution?